# Tables referencing each other workaround

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have two tables (simplified):

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        article                          |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int          | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| author      | int          | FK (users)                 |
| created_at  | date         |                            |
| revision    | int          | FK (article_revision)      |                  
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                   article_revision                      |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int          | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| title       | text         |                            |
| content     | text         |                            |
| article_id  | int          | FOREIGN KEY (article)      |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

They are representing news feed articles. Every article can have multiple revisions (changes). I need somehow to specify a current revision from **article** table which is used (there can be **pending** revisions that can be used, only one at the time). But it would be circular references. Any workaround for this situation?

Comment: Which column(s) let us know what is the current revision?

Comment: Maybe make an additional "active_revision" table which just matches one article to one revision?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that is the problem, I don't know how to properly represent it in the table (article) without circular references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that keeps you from adding circular foreign key references.

To deal with them, you only have to make sure that at the end of each statement or transaction, all constraints are satisfied:

- If you use normal `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraints, you have to modify both tables in a single statement:

  ```
  WITH current_revision AS (
     INSERT INTO article_revision VALUES (...) RETURNING id
  )
  UPDATE article
  FROM current_revision
  SET revision = current_revision.id
  WHERE ...;
  ```
- With `DEFERRABLE` foreign keys, the check is deferred to the end of the transaction:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO article_revision VALUES (...) RETURNING id;
  UPDATE article SET revision = ... WHERE ...;
  COMMIT;
  ```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. Sure you would. Only those suffering the same affliction would understand.